# How to change the status of the directory file in tcl?

Tags: linux, tcl

The thing is, I was assigned to do a tcl script that can change the status of the directory file. I used the `file stat *name* array` command to display the inodes, like this:

```
file stat $f arr

if { $g eq "size" } { 
  puts "size: $arr(size)"
}
if { $g eq "inode" } {
  puts "inode: $arr(ino)"
}
if { $g eq "type" } {
  puts "type: $arr(type)"
}
```

...

What should I use to change it? All I can do for now is to access and display it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any research effort.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? What do you mean by 'change the status of the directory'? What should be different after your changed it?

Comment: Thank you for the response, to explain, i've read about file atime ?name? ?time?, if time is specified, it is an access time to set for the file. Then I tried to use it to assign new accesss time to the file, nothing happens. The same thing happens with mtime. I tried these things to change some inodes in the status of a directory or a file. I hope you understand what I want to say. Thank you.

Comment: @keemoosu Ok, that is much clearer. Did you use `file atime $f time` where `time` is time in POSIX format? You are also re-running `file stat $f arr` after running the `file atime $f time` again to check the updated value of `atime`, right?

Comment: Right @Jerry i'm using POSIX format, yet when i rerun the whole script, the same access time is shown. The access time should be changed after running the script one time right?

Comment: @keemoosu Right. I cannot reproduce that behaviour on my machine. I called: `file stat test.txt arr; puts $arr(atime)` I get 1395689199, then run `file atime test.txt 1395689000; file stat test.txt arr; puts $arr(atime)` and I get 1395689000.

Comment: ahh okay, thanks @Jerry , got it. meaning, that's also the way how to modify the mtime. then the ctime will also changed. my other concern is, is it possible to change the device and number of link of the file/directory?

Comment: @keemoosu Sorry, I don't know about those :(

Comment: You can't change the `dev`ice or `ino`de; they're managed entirely by the OS. The `link` count can be changed (on Unix; no idea about Windows) by making additional hard links. `file link` can be used to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Not everything in the OS `stat` structure (which `file stat` really wraps) is modifiable by user code. Some things are managed by the OS entirely, and are set at the time of the creation of the “file” and cannot be altered later. For example, you can't change the `type`: a `file` isn't a `directory` or a `socket` or … and the device and inode number are effectively a unique identifier for the file independent of its name and never change.

The `atime` and `mtime` fields can be set (via `file atime` and `file mtime`) and the permissions bits via `file attributes`. The ownership fields are theoretically settable (also via `file attributes`) but you probably haven't got permission to do so, and the `link` count is sort-of settable by creating hard links (with `file link`) or deleting them (`file delete`).

The `size` just reflects how many bytes are in the file: don't think of setting it so much as writing to the file.

Comment: Thank you @Donal Fellows I really searched hard for that information, good thing to have your immediate response. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!